# length of SafeUnicode inside django template

Tags: python, django

I noticed that if you pass a variable called some_copy containing a unicode string into a Django template:

```
some_copy <type 'unicode'>
some_copy|length <type 'int'> 
some_copy|safe <class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode'>
some_copy|safe|length <class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeString'>
```

I noticed that the length filter is just calling `len()` on the input, so tested importing `django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode` on a terminal and it seems to just return `<type 'int'>` when you call `len()`.  Is there something strange here about how the safe filter interacts with other filters?  I know there are notes suggesting not to use other filters after safe as they could render the output less safe.  Also, this code was producing a bug and no longer contains the calls to `safe|length`, but I was curious what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code:

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def length(value):
    """Returns the length of the value - useful for lists."""
    try:
        return len(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return ''
```

The `@register.filter(is_safe=True)` tells Django to convert the output of the `length` function to a `SaveData` subclass instance by calling `mark_safe`. In the case of an integer input, `mark_safe` returns a `SafeString` instance.